# Where am I going wrong in coding(output:0)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

## !/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

def shell():

```
 return subprocess.call(["bash","test.sh"])
```

file=raw_input("enter the absolute path of a directory:-")

file_obj=open("test.sh",'wb+')

file_obj.write("echo `ls %s`" %file)

file_obj.closed

print shell()

Comment: What is the content of the file `test.sh` after you run the program?

Comment: test will contain echo `ls <the given file with absolute path>`                             then i want to execute the test.sh file and print the output . but i am getting 0 as my output. why??????

Comment: I meant, "what is the actual content of the file?", not "what do you want the file to contain?"

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't return anything. You call `subprocess.call` but you don't return it. You're trying to print the return value of the function, but there isn't any so you get `None`.

For example

```
def foo():
    return 5

def bar():
    #do nothing

print foo()
print bar()
```

will output

```
5
None
```

because `foo()` returns 5 whereas `bar()` doesn't return anything.

**EDIT**

You seem to want the output of the command, I'm assuming. If you read the documentation for [`subprocess` here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) you'll see that `subprocess.call` returns the exit code, not the output.

What you want is `subprocess.check_output()`. See [here (on the same page)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

> Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.
>
> If the return code was non-zero it raises a `CalledProcessError`. The `CalledProcessError` object will have the return code in the `returncode` attribute and any output in the `output` attribute.

Example from the docs:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
'Hello World!\n'

>>> subprocess.check_output("exit 1", shell=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'exit 1' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: def shell():
   return subprocess.call(["bash","test.sh"])                                                            print shell()                                                                                                                 now the output is 0                                                                                            what to do ?